# grepping for a large binary value from an even larger binary file

Tags: linux, search, command-line, binary, grep

As the title suggests I would like to grep a reasonably large (about 100MB) binary file, for a binary string - this binary string is just under 5K.

I've tried grep using the -P option, but this only seems to return matches when the pattern is only a few bytes - when I go up to about 100 bytes it no longer finds any matches.

I've also tried [bgrep](http://debugmo.de/2009/04/bgrep-a-binary-grep).  This worked well originally, however, when I needed to extend the pattern to the length I have now I just get "invalid/empty search string" errors.

The irony is, in Windows I can use HxD to search the file and I finds it in a instance.  What I really need though is a Linux command line tool.

Thanks for your help,

Simon

Comment: We really need more info on the search pattern. Note that perl -P expects perl-style regular expressions. Is that really what you wanted? AFAICT HxD doesn't support regexes at all...

Comment: Not really.  -P is just something I've use in the past to get grep to find binary matches for me.  I don't really care about reg-ex at all.  I just need to look for a large, static, binary pattern across a number of files.

Answer (score 2):

Say we have a couple of big binary data files. For a big one that shouldn't match, we create a 100MB file whose contents are all NUL bytes.

```
dd ibs=1 count=100M if=/dev/zero of=allzero.dat
```

For the one we want to match, create a hundred random megabytes.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;

binmode STDOUT or die "$0: binmode: $!";

for (1 .. 100 * 1024 * 1024) {
  print chr rand 256;
}
```

Execute it as `./mkrand >myfile.dat`.

Finally, extract a known match into a file named `pattern`.

```
dd skip=42 count=10 if=myfile.dat of=pattern
```

I assume you want only the files that match (`-l`) and want your pattern to be treated literally (`-F` or `--fixed-strings`). I suspect you may have been running into a length limit with `-P`.

You may be tempted to use the `--file=PATTERN-FILE` option, but `grep` interprets the contents of *PATTERN-FILE* as newline-separated patterns, so in the likely case that your 5KB pattern contains newlines, you'll hit an encoding problem.

So hope your system's `ARG_MAX` is big enough and go for it. Be sure to quote the contents of `pattern`. For example:

```
$ grep -l --fixed-strings "$(cat pattern)" allzero.dat myfile.dat
myfile.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `grep -U` which treats files as binary.

Also, how are you specifying the search pattern? It might just need escaping to survive shell parameter expansions

Comment: Currently I'm using grep -U -P "\xE1\x01\x08\x73\xE3\x03...." bigfile. How would I do the escaping?  Also, is there some way of getting grep to read the pattern from a file?  I tried -f but that didn't work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the string you are searching is pretty long. You could benefit by an implementation of the Boyer-Moore search algorithm which is very efficient when search string is very long

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

The wiki also has links to some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at  a simple Python script.

```
match= (b"..." 
    b"...."
    b"..." ) # Some byte string literal of immense proportions
with open("some_big_file","rb") as source:
    block= read(len(match))
    while block != match:
        byte= read(1)
        if not byte: break
        block= block[1:]+read(1)
```

This might work reliably under Linux as well as Windows.